# jhipster-entity-audit @Inject issue

Tags: jhipster

I am using generator-jhipster 4.0.7 and I ve created a project, and I want to create new entity with auditing. The netity is created succesfully but the audit generator is creating dependencies with @Inject, which is not a part of the current jhipster version. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple way will be to add the javax.inject dependencies to your project i.e. pom.xml if you are having a maven project or to your build.gradle if you have a gradle project.

for maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

for gradle:

```
compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
```

You need to check if by adding this dependencies you are not getting any conflicts in your project. This is something what I can't say because I don't know what other libs are you using.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I have thought that way but i was wondering if there is a more "automated" solution because as you said it may have conflicts with other libs.

Comment: I gues it  should not be a problem to remove the inject annotation and create the proper constructor. Or add the javax.inject lib to classpath and watch if there are any problems. I think it should not create any problems because the DI container, in this case spring, can handle both way of injection. This can be a intermediate solution until the project is updated:
https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit